# Change color of active menu on Scroll JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a script to change the color of navigation links on scroll, but I am not getting how to do it for active link, can someone help?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 100) {
jQuery(".current-menu-item").addClass("current-menu-item-sticky");
}
else{
jQuery(".current-menu-item").removeClass("current-menu-item-sticky");
}
});
});
</script>
```

This class code is responsible for color, how can I update color on scroll?

```
.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

Comment: By adding `.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.current-menu-item-sticky a { color: #f00 !important; }`

Comment: how can I implement it into JQuery?

Comment: You can do `jQuery('.et_pb_menu_0_tb_header.et_pb_menu ul li.current-menu-item-sticky a').css('color', 'red !important');` but you might have to remove the other rule's `!important` for that to work.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is to change the class on scroll and by using another class I can apply another css.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but your code is *already adding the class*, so you shouldn't need additional jQuery commands to change the link color, just a rule like in my first comment. I don't understand what the issue is. What exactly is not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide the markup, u could still solve this by making the css selectors broader, the class `current-menu-item-sticky` that is added on scroll doesn´t even exist in your css.

so to start off just use this css

```
.current-menu-item-sticky {
   color:#fff!important;
}
```

If that doesn´t change anything, the reason is clear to me, all other color css should not have !important or have the right order so the correct !important will be applied.

You can easily use the element-inspector of your browser and see what css is applied and what css is overriden